# Extract tree from cpio archive

Tags: rpm, cpio

I have an RPM contaning files in `./var/lib` which I need to extract onto my filesystem on a Debian machine. I'm trying to do this:

```
rpm2cpio myrpm.rpm | cpio -ivd ./var/lib
```

Nothis is extracted. If I specify the full path to the exact file which I want, I get it, but I need to extract the entire tree.

How can I extract the entire tree (ie: all files within a directory in the RPM) to the local filesystem?

Comment: Not sure why the directory argument is not working.  This works for me:  `cd <destdir>; rpm2cpio /path/to/rpm | cpio -idmv`

Comment: 1. Have you considered using Debian's `alien` to do this for you? 2. Does `rpm2cpio` generate paths starting `./`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was ultimately able to do it using something like this:

```
rpm2cpio myrpm.rpm | cpio -ivd './var/lib/**/*'
```